# Is there any difference between variable usage and double exclamation in an if?

Tags: javascript

Let's suppose I have a variable `condition`. If I want to store it into a variable as a strict `boolean` value, then I do something like this:

```
var logicalCondition = !!condition;
```

The first exclamation negates `condition` and converts the value into a `boolean`. The second exclamation negates the negated strict boolean value back. The result is `true` if `condition` was truey and is `false` if `condition` is falsy. `If` conditions are known to convert truey to `true` and falsy to `false`. So, if we take a look at the following two chunks

```
//first
if (condition) {
    //do something
}

//second
if (!!condition) {
    //do something
}
```

the first difference we can observe is that in the second case we convert the value into strict `boolean` value before we hand it to the `if`. Is there a second difference, or is this conversion unnecessary?

Comment: No difference. `!!` is an implicit conversion to boolean but `if(condition)` also takes truthy/falsey values and it does the same either way

Comment: It is unnecessary. The behavior of the `if` condition test is exactly the same as the result of `!!`.

Comment: May be linter less complains with that? like automatic type detection and it is not boolean.

Comment: I just like to point out that while `if(!!condition)` is superflous, it works to instruct the next person who looks at the code that `condition` is not actually a boolean. So, it has some value for maintenance, even if there is no difference for the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a second difference...?

No, there isn't, at the JavaScript engine's level. As you've said, the test done by `if` (and anywhere else a boolean is required) will do the same thing that `!!` is doing (in effect). So your first difference (the extra work) is the only difference.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, that confirms my opinion prior to asking the question.

Comment: @LajosArpad: Yeah, we could kind of tell. :-)